# Terminal behaving strangely

Tags: c

When I run a C program the terminal prompt gets erased. The program just prints out a line from a file. This always happens when I run this program . Is there some problem with my bash?

```
FILE* f; 
...open, read a line
printf("%s", line);
```

Comment: what's the line? what's the file?

Answer (score 5):

There might be a carriage return (\r) character in your file which causes prompt to get erased as cursor is positioned to start of line.

Comment: Yes - there is. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

To remove the problem with the '\r' character that Bug Catcher suggested just run your file through dos2unix. Should fix the problem.